# MapControl events not firing; detect user interaction

Tags: c#, uwp

I want to detect when a user starts dragging a `MapControl` to detach from the center of the screen, however NONE of the `Drag*` events is fired.

```
 map.MapTapped += Map_MapTapped;
 map.ActualCameraChanged += Map_ActualCameraChanged;
 map.DragEnter += Map_DragEnter;
 map.DragStarting += Map_DragStarting;
 map.DragLeave += Map_DragLeave;
 map.DragOver += Map_DragOver;
 map.ManipulationStarted += Map_ManipulationStarted;
 map.Tapped += Map_Tapped;
 map.PointerPressed += Map_PointerPressed;
 map.PointerMoved += Map_PointerMoved;
```

The only events that I see fired are `MapTapped` and `ActualCameraChanged` but both of these events don't fire on drag, when I need them.

Comment: If this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45399826/7331395) works then consider Mark as Answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`ActualCameraChanging`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.maps.mapcontrol#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Maps_MapControl_ActualCameraChanging) to rise event while dragging

```
<Maps:MapControl Name="MyMap" ActualCameraChanging="MyMap_ActualCameraChanging"/>
```

Use [`ChangeReason`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps.MapTargetCameraChangedEventArgs#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Maps_MapTargetCameraChangedEventArgs_ChangeReason) to check the reason for dragging

```
private void MyMap_ActualCameraChanging(MapControl sender, MapActualCameraChangingEventArgs args)
{
    if(args.ChangeReason == MapCameraChangeReason.UserInteraction)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: `TransformOriginChanged` does not fire, and `CenterChanged` fires when I interact with the map programatically, which I don't want. Only human interaction.

Comment: @Gala What about `MapHolding`?

Comment: That's a long press.